# get the result from table which is in relation or not in relation

Tags: sql

I have a table in that table 4 column Id , FirmId, OfficeId, PlanID
Data Like Below

```
Id  FirmId  OfficeId    PlanID
-----------------------------------------
1   54      NULL        4
2   54      3           9
3   54      5           8
4   54      6           6
5   54      7           9
6   54      8           8
```

i have 4 Table Firm, Office, Plan, FirmOfficePlan 
in FirmOfficePlan Contains Firm plan  and Office Plan 
like firm 54 has a 10 office 
Firm 54 has a plan id = 4  and Office id = NULL

but in Some of Office of 54 has a different plan like Office 3 has a Plan id = 9 ,Office 5 has a plan id = 8, Office 6 has a planid = 6

so rest of office has a refer a plan = 4 (Which is configure for Firm)

So i want to get result for All Offices like Below

```
Id  FirmId  OfficeId    PlanID
--------------------------------------
1   54      1           4
1   54      2           4
2   54      3           9
3   54      5           8
4   54      6           6
5   54      7           9
6   54      8           8
1   54      9           4
1   54      10          4
```

i have 80000+ firm and 30 to 40 office each firm in this case it will work very slow
Below is My Query But i am Not Satisfy

```
SELECT  A.Firm_Id,
        A.Office_id,
        PricingPlanId = COALESCE(B.PlanId,A.PlanId)
FROM    (SELECT A.Firm_Id,O.Office_id,A.PlanId  
        FROM    Firm F
                Inner Join Office O ON  O.Firm_Id = F.Firm_Id
                Left Join FirmOfficePlan A ON A.Firm_Id = F.Firm_ID 
                                                      AND A.Office_Id IS Null   
        WHERE   F.Firm_ID = 54)A
        LEFT JOIN FirmOfficePlan B ON A.Firm_ID  = B.Firm_ID 
                                               AND A.Office_id =  B.Office_Id
                                               AND B.Office_Id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I don't quite get how you arrive to your desired outcome, can you write it again with proper punctuation marks?

Comment: Hello EzLo i have updated the question

Comment: Odd, the expected result contains OfficeId 10, which doesn't exists in the table.

Comment: yes , because of **FirmOfficePlan**  does not contains that office id 10 record , but  **office** table contains the record